# How to open the search by clicking a custom button in android?

Tags: android, search, google-search, buttonclick

I want to open the search (Default Search), which stays on the desktop (the google search) by clicking a button.

Here is the Xml code:

```
 <ImageButton 
     android:id="@+id/btnSearch" 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search" android:text="" 
 />
```

which I used to create the button. It's a very simple button. Now I used this `onclicklistener` to catch the click event of that button :

```
imgSearch.setOnClickListener(
    new View.OnClickListener() { 
        @Override public void onClick(View v) { 
            onSearchRequested(); 
        } 
    }
);
```

But couldn't find out how to exactly make it work. Please Let me know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Intent` class with web search action:

```
private void onSearchRequested() { 

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
    intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, "your search query");
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

Comment: Many Many thanks for the code @tpbapp. It did the job for me. Now I can initiate the web search directly by clicking the button. Thanks again.